# How to create a block diagonal sparse matrix using Eigen lib in c++?

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix, eigen

I want to create a cost matrix similar to the below using Eigen lib where Q, QN and R are some square matrices and N is a number, i.e., 20.

```
from scipy import sparse

P = sparse.block_diag([sparse.kron(sparse.eye(self.N), self.Q), self.QN,
         sparse.kron(sparse.eye(self.N), self.R)], format='csc')
```

I could not find any proper API in Eigen lib. The following approach that I used to construct the P matrix,

```
Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> cost_;
cost_.resize(N, N);
cost_.setIdentity();


Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> stateCost =  Eigen::kroneckerProduct(cost_,  model.Q).eval();
Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> controlCost =  Eigen::kroneckerProduct(cost_,  model.R).eval();
Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> P;
P.resize((N+1)*numState+numInput*N, (N+1)*numState+numInput*N);
P.setZero();

for(int i=0; i<(N)*numState; i+=numState){
    for(int j=0; j<numState; j++){
        for(int k=0; k<numState; k++){
            P.coeffRef(i+j, i+k) = stateCost.coeffRef(i+j, i+k);
        }
    }
}
for(int i=(N)*numState; i<(N+1)*numState; i+=numState){
    for(int j=0; j<numState; j++){
        for(int k=0; k<numState; k++){
            P.coeffRef(i+j, i+k) =  model.QN.coeffRef(j, k);
        }
    }
}
int index = 0;
for(int i=(N+1)*numState; i<(N+1)*numState+numInput*N; i+=numInput){
    for(int j=0; j<numInput; j++){
        for(int k=0; k<numInput; k++){
            P.coeffRef(i+j, i+k) = controlCost.coeffRef(index+j, index+k);
        }
    }
index += numInput;
}
```

If other efficient way of doing this please let me know? I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30169053/eigen-library-how-do-i-create-a-block-diagonal-sparse-matrix-out-of-existing-s), seems to be its really old,

Comment: The pgython code for you example code is conceptually quite simple.  Read it.  It combines the `coo` attributes of the inputs with suitable row/column offsets to make new `coo` matrix.  And a final conversion to `csc` format.

Comment: @hpaulj yeap I want to write it c++ using Eigen Sparse matrices  I understand what's going on, the only concern is that the way it is written is good enough in terms of performance